# Gradle successfully build but no apk file generated

Tags: android, proguard

Firstly, i need to explain what I am doing, I am building an aar, which will be running on another app calling an activity belongs to the aar.
The aar is  running fine. So it is time for me to try to hide away the aar source code using proguard. However, I can successfully build, but no apk is generated. Anyone know why? I have attached info maybe needed below, please ask if I missed anything. Only if debug without using proguard, I can see there is apk generated.

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword KEY_PASSWORD
            storePassword STORE_PASSWORD
            storeFile file(STORE_FILE)
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "boolean", "LOGGABLE", "false"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false            
        }
        pre_release {
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "boolean", "LOGGABLE", "true"
        }
    }

    //sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = []
    // disable automatic ndk-build call, which ignore our Android.mk
    sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile files('libs/pass-v1.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/sdk-v1.0.0.jar')


    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'io.card:android-sdk:5.3.4'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.3'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
    compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.0@aar'
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'

    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.0'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.splunk.mint:mint:5.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.3.1'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.loopeer.library:cardstack:1.0.1'
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.4.1'


//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'  //commented to avoid app crash on xiomi devices, extended application to multi dex app
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.0'
    compile project(path: ':app')
    compile project(path: ':app')
    compile project(path: ':app')
    compile project(path: ':app')

}
```

proguard rules:

```
-dontwarn org.joda.convert.FromString
-dontwarn org.joda.convert.ToString



#GSON 2.2.4 specific rules ##

# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keepattributes EnclosingMethod

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }


# keep samsung sdk classes
# -keep class com.samsung.android.**{*;}
 -dontwarn com.samsung.android.**
 -dontnote com.samsung.android.**


#for fabric Crashlytics
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-keep class com.crashlytics.android.**
-keepattributes SourceFile, LineNumberTable, *Annotation*


# Butter Knife
-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}

#ormlite new
# for ormlite stuff
-keep class com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** {*;}
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.**  {*;}
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.**  {*;}

# keep the classes and members of our entities or OrmLite will not work
-keep class com.korvac.liquid.model.**
-keepclassmembers com.korvac.liquid.model.** {*;}
-keep class com.korvac.liquid.activity.**
-keepclassmembers com.korvac.liquid.activity.** {*;}

# OrmLite
-keep class com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }

# Picasso
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

#Retrofit
# Retrofit 2.X
## https://square.github.io/retrofit/ ##

-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}


# Rxjava
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {
    public static <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.ImmediateScheduler {
    public <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.TestScheduler {
    public <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {
    public static ** test();
}
-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.*ArrayQueue*Field* {
    long producerIndex;
    long consumerIndex;
}
-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueProducerNodeRef {
    long producerNode;
    long consumerNode;
}

# Model
-keep class com.korvac.liquid.model.** { *; }

# HttpResponse
-keep class com.korvac.liquid.network.response.HttpResponse { *; }

# SwipeRefreshLayout
-keepclassmembers class * extends com.korvac.liquid.fragment.BaseFragment {
    *;
}
-keep class **$Properties

# GMS
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

# MPAndroidChart
-keep class com.github.mikephil.charting.** { *; }
-dontwarn io.realm.**

# Sweet Alert
-keep class cn.pedant.SweetAlert.Rotate3dAnimation {
   public <init>(...);
}

#gif drawable
-keep public class pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifIOException{<init>(int);}
-keep class pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifInfoHandle{<init>(long,int,int,int);}

# appcompat
-keep public class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.** { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
}

# Updated as of Stetho 1.1.1
#
# Note: Doesn't include Javascript console lines. See https://github.com/facebook/stetho/tree/master/stetho-js-rhino#proguard
-keep class com.facebook.stetho.** { *; }

# Okio
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-dontwarn java.nio.file.*
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
-dontwarn okio.**
```

Gradle log:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDevDebugSources, :app:generateDevDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:prepareDevDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :sdk:generateReleaseSources, :sdk:prepareReleaseUnitTestDependencies, :sdk:mockableAndroidJar]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDevDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDevDebugManifest
:app:preDevPre_releaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDevReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preProDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preProPre_releaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preProReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareCnPedantSweetalertLibrary13Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDevDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preProDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidAnswers139Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidBeta122Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlytics262Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlyticsCore2311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComDlazaro66QrcodereaderviewQrcodereaderview200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase961Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement961Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm961Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid961Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation961Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps961Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks961Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComLoopeerLibraryCardstack101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComMakeramenRoundedimageview221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComPnikosisMaterialishProgress10Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComSoundcloudAndroidAndroidCrop100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDeHdodenhofCircleimageview200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareIoCardAndroidSdk534Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareIoFabricSdkAndroidFabric1313Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareIoReactivexRxandroid110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareNetDanlewAndroidJoda2941Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:preparePlDroidsonroidsGifAndroidGifDrawable120Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDevDebugDependencies
:app:compileDevDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDevDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDevDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDevDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDevDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDevDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDevDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDevDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:fabricGenerateResourcesDevDebug
:app:generateDevDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDevDebugResources
:app:mergeDevDebugResources
:app:processDevDebugResources
:app:generateDevDebugSources
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidexInstrumentation101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDevDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDevDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDevDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDevDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDevDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDevDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDevDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDevDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDevDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDevDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDevDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDevDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:sdk:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:sdk:extractProguardFiles
:sdk:preReleaseBuild
:sdk:checkReleaseManifest
:sdk:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:sdk:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:sdk:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:sdk:prePre_releaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:sdk:prePre_releaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:sdk:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:sdk:prepareCnPedantSweetalertLibrary13Library
:sdk:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library
:sdk:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library
:sdk:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2340Library
:sdk:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library
:sdk:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72340Library
:sdk:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42400Library
:sdk:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library
:sdk:prepareComDlazaro66QrcodereaderviewQrcodereaderview200Library
:sdk:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase961Library
:sdk:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement961Library
:sdk:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm961Library
:sdk:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid961Library
:sdk:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation961Library
:sdk:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps961Library
:sdk:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks961Library
:sdk:prepareComLoopeerLibraryCardstack101Library
:sdk:prepareComMakeramenRoundedimageview221Library
:sdk:prepareComPnikosisMaterialishProgress10Library
:sdk:prepareComSoundcloudAndroidAndroidCrop100Library
:sdk:prepareDeHdodenhofCircleimageview200Library
:sdk:prepareIoCardAndroidSdk534Library
:sdk:prepareIoReactivexRxandroid110Library
:sdk:prepareNetDanlewAndroidJoda2941Library
:sdk:preparePlDroidsonroidsGifAndroidGifDrawable120Library
:sdk:prepareReleaseDependencies
:sdk:compileReleaseAidl
:sdk:compileReleaseRenderscript
:sdk:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:sdk:generateReleaseResValues
:sdk:generateReleaseResources
:sdk:mergeReleaseResources
:sdk:processReleaseManifest
:sdk:processReleaseResources
:sdk:generateReleaseSources
:sdk:prepareReleaseUnitTestDependencies
:sdk:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 24.768 secs
```

Comment: APK shouldn't be generated for the `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` since it is not an application. Only case to generate APK for it is the Android unit testing APK.

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko so how can i obfuscate my aar code? Is there a way?

Comment: just build a release configuration, and obfuscated AAR should appear on the `build\outputs\aar` path

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko Tried, only project\build\generated   and project\build\intermediates  generated.     OR   project\sdk\build\generated and   project\sdk\build\intermediates  and  project\sdk\build\tmp

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko if using debug build, i will see the aar file generated in project\sdk\build\output\xxx.aar

Comment: you can try running `assembleRelease` or `sdk:assembleRelease`, if your library module name is `sdk`